# 'error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function'

Tags: windows-7, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005, xerces-c

I'm trying to build xercesc 3.1 on 64bit Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2005. I downloaded the source from the official site and followed the [instructions given there](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html#Windows) (basically, just 'open the .sln and build project XercesLib), but I get the following compilation errors:

```
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandset' not allowed
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandreset' not allowed
```

I noticed that the SDK version in this error message was **6.1** whereas **7.0** was released with Windows 7. So I tried adding `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include` to the Additional Include Directories of the project, but this had no effect.

I also checked that I had opened the right sln file - I went with the one labelled 'VC8', which  I believe should correspond to VS2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching with different terms, I discovered that this is a [known bug in VS2005](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/100051) when including both winnt.h and intrin.h.

The easiest workaround for this is to use the preprocessor to [rename the offending functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Build_Instructions/Intrin.h) when including one of the headers.

However, in the case of Xercesc, the functions are used, so a little more work is required. I used the solution detailed in [this blog post](https://blog.assarbad.net/20120425/annoyance-in-the-windows-sdk-headers/):

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
//  Following 8 lines: workaround for a bug in some older SDKs
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandset")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandset64")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset64")
#   define _interlockedbittestandset _local_interlockedbittestandset
#   define _interlockedbittestandreset _local_interlockedbittestandreset
#   define _interlockedbittestandset64 _local_interlockedbittestandset64
#   define _interlockedbittestandreset64 _local_interlockedbittestandreset64
#   include <intrin.h> // to force the header not to be included elsewhere
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset64")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandset64")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandset")
#endif
```

Which allowed compilation to complete error-free.

Comment: This solution must be used prior to *any* other headers that may include `intrin.h` on their own. Just keep that in mind.